# How sklearn logistic regression computes accuracy, recall etc if we don't provide threshold?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

It might be a stupid question, but I just realized that calling `score` function on logistic regression model shouldn't make any sense - as far as I know in sklearn we cannot specify threshold for `model.predict` called during evaluation, so we might be using suboptimal threshold and thus accuracy doesn't tell much about the model. I know how to extract probs from model and try different thresholds on my own, but asking if there is any point of using accuracy as a metric in cross-validation etc?? I would use `roc_auc` instead every time.

Answer (score 2):

The default threshold is 0.5, so it is computed on that basis. It is kind of a problem as it isn't well documented (not even on the logistic regression predict page) and a very common pitfall.

The two most common approach are either to use another metric (auc is a good exemple, proper scoring rule might be even better), the other approach is to buil a custom prediction function so as to incorporate your own threshold in your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks :) what do you mean by "proper scoring rule"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule typically... the idea is to use metrics that translate the probability being well calibrated

Comment: @Icrmorin thanks again, for some reason I've never heard about proper scoring rules - I'll read about it and hopefully learn something important.

Comment: I would say that for Logistic Regression threshold 0.5 is more or less justified, as typically Logistic Regression is used on top of other classifiers to make probabilities calibrated.

Comment: Its far from being the main usecase. Ideally the theshold shoud be set depending on the cost of Type I and Type II errors.